# How to remove duplication from unit tests JEST?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Yesterday, I wrote a unit test with  [Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect) and Today I figure out that I made some duplicated code that does the same test.

I have a file: `null.spec.js` that contain these tests :

```
import ArrayNull from "../../../../../src/1.x.x/scripts/array/has/null";

describe("Array has any null value", () => {
     
    .......

    it("should throw error if the parameter is not an array", () => {
        function passNumber() {
            ArrayNull.hasAnyNull(0);
        }
        function passString() {
            ArrayNull.hasAnyNull("item");
        }
        expect(passNumber).toThrowError("The parameter should be an array");
        expect(passString).toThrowError("The parameter should be an array");
    });
    it("should throw error if the parameter is undefined or null", () => {
        function passUndefinedOrNull() {
            ArrayNull.hasAnyNull(undefined || null);
        }
        expect(passUndefinedOrNull).toThrowError("The parameter is null or undefined");
    });
    it("should throw error if the array is empty", () => {
        function pasEmptyArray() {
            ArrayNull.hasAnyNull([]);
        }
        expect(pasEmptyArray).toThrowError("The array is empty");
    });
});


describe("Array has at least a null value", () => {
   ...........

    it("should throw error if the parameter is not an array", () => {
        function passNumber() {
            ArrayNull.hasAtLeastNull(0);
        }
        function passString() {
            ArrayNull.hasAtLeastNull("item");
        }
        expect(passNumber).toThrowError("The parameter should be an array");
        expect(passString).toThrowError("The parameter should be an array");
    });
    it("should throw error if the array is empty", () => {
        function pasEmptyArray() {
            ArrayNull.hasAtLeastNull([]);
        }
        expect(pasEmptyArray).toThrowError("The array is empty");
    });
    it("should throw error when the parameter is undefined or null", () => {
        function passUndefinedOrNull() {
            ArrayNull.hasAtLeastNull(undefined || null);
        }
        expect(passUndefinedOrNull).toThrowError("The parameter is null or undefined");
    });
});
```

Look how I wrote redundantly `it("should throw an error if the parameter is not an array", callback`) in each test even it does the same thing: Throw an error but with **Different Functions**

- The first funtion is: `hasAnyNull()`
- The second function is: `hasAtLeastNull()`

How can I remove this duplication between `describe("Array has any null value", callback)` and

`describe("Array has at least a null value", callback`)`?

Comment: Don’t worry about duplication in tests. DRY is a tool to help write better code, not a goal in itself.

Comment: Yes, but it's not Automated, I mean I do it by hand and it takes unnecessary time and may lead to silent bugs ( from Typo-error).

Comment: Write more detailed tests so they wouldn't become false positive from a typo. Use TypeScript to avoid more errors from typos.

Comment: @EstusFlask, could you review my answer, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the DRY problem by :

0. Make all `errors` throwing in one `it("should throw an error")` without details.
1. implementing top-level function `_throwError(func)` .
2. Pass a callback `func` inside it.

**Previous Code :**

```
it("should throw error if the parameter is not an array", () => {
        function passNumber() {
            ArrayNull.hasAnyNull(0);
        }
        function passString() {
            ArrayNull.hasAnyNull("item");
        }
        expect(passNumber).toThrowError("The parameter should be an array");
        expect(passString).toThrowError("The parameter should be an array");
    });
    it("should throw error if the parameter is undefined or null", () => {
        function passUndefinedOrNull() {
            ArrayNull.hasAnyNull(undefined || null);
        }
        expect(passUndefinedOrNull).toThrowError("The parameter is null or undefined");
    });
    it("should throw error if the array is empty", () => {
        function pasEmptyArray() {
            ArrayNull.hasAnyNull([]);
        }
        expect(pasEmptyArray).toThrowError("The array is empty");
    });
```

**Current Code :**

```
it("should throw an error", () => {
        __throwError(ArrayNull.hasAnyNull);
    });
```

**__throwError Function:**

```
    function __throwError(func) {

    function passNumber() {
        func.length === 1 ? func(0) : func(0, 1)
    }

    function passString() {
        func.length === 1 ? func("item") : func("item", 1);
    }

    function passEmptyArray() {
        func.length === 1 ? func([]) : func([], 1);
    }

    function passUndefinedOrNull() {
        func.length === 1 ? func(undefined || null) : func(undefined || null, 1);
    }

    expect(passNumber).toThrowError("The parameter should be an array");
    expect(passString).toThrowError("The parameter should be an array");
    expect(passEmptyArray).toThrowError("The array is empty");
    expect(passUndefinedOrNull).toThrowError("The parameter is null or undefined");

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant regarding DRY vs WET. __throwError adds complexity without a good reason and falls into unnecessary abstraction category, which is an antipattern. It's more of write-only code that makes sense when you write it but hurts the maintenance, after a while it will take time to figure out what exactly it does and, more importantly, whether it does it correctly. This is not a thing you want in tests, where KISS beats DRY. It makes sense to refactor 10 such cases for a good common denominator, but 2 of them is not enough for good DRY solution.

Comment: There was a meaningful write-up by Dan Abramov on preliminary refactoring https://overreacted.io/goodbye-clean-code/ .

Comment: @EstusFlask but I reduced the test from 85 into 67 and the time of execution.

Comment: This shouldn't be a priority if the quality of tests is compromised. If the goal was to reduce tests count and thus the time of execution, you could do more assertions in less tests the same way you did with __throwError but without it. As for tests count, it's not necessarily a good thing. The less test report is specific regarding the cause of the problem, the more it will require to investigate into test code.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple test blocks can be generated by iterating over values:

```
[
  ['has any null', hasAnyNull],
  ['has at least a null', hasAtLeastNull]
].forEach(([description, fn]) => {
  describe(`Array ${description} value`, () => {
    it(...);
  });
});
```

This can be done in-place or extracted to a helper function.

When it comes to repeated `describe` blocks, this is exactly what `describe.each` does, with the addition of description formatting:

```
describe.each([
  ['has any null', hasAnyNull],
  ['has at least a null', hasAtLeastNull]
])('Array %s value', (_description, fn) => {
   it(...);
});
```

Deduplication isn't an end in itself. If DRY code becomes less readable and error-prone than WET code this may be a problem in application code but it is certainly a problem in tests. If application code fails the expectations because of complexity, this is expected to be detected in tests; this doesn't apply to tests themselves.

Comment: I guess your answer shows me another issue in the code.